# How do you have multiple forms and only submit one at a time in MVC 5 view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

When ever i try to submit a form after the first, it just calls that post method instead of the one for the form that the submit button currently is inside of. I was under the impression that whatever form your submit butto is inside of is the one that will be triggered on the page.

Using ajax  helper functions to get around it but it was not working how i wanted it to.

Below are some chunks of the code [here](https://hastebin.com/ayujebekih.cshtml) is the full one.

```
            Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comments", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-control" });
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Hidden("BlogPostId", Model.Id);
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        @Html.Editor("Content", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "richTextEditor", @class = "form-control textarea", @placeholder = "Enter comment here.", @rows = 5, @cols = 10 } })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="padding-top:2%">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Comments", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-control" }))
                                            {
                                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                                @Html.Hidden("Id", comment.Id);
                                                @Html.Hidden("BlogPostId", comment.BlogPostId);
                                                @Html.Hidden("AuthorId", comment.AuthorId);
                                                @Html.Hidden("CreateDate", comment.CreateDate);
                                                @Html.Hidden("UpdateDate", comment.UpdateDate);
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    @Html.Editor("UpdateReason", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter comment here.", @rows = 5, @cols = 10 } })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    @Html.Editor("Content", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "richTextCommentEditor", @class = "form-control textarea", @placeholder = "Enter comment here.", @rows = 5, @cols = 10 } })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row" style="padding-top:2%">
                                                <div class="col-2">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Submit</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        }
```

Im not getting any errors, it is just causing the action for the creawtion of comment be called instead of the action that the form SHOULD be going to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forms will not know what actions you are trying to submit unless you define the action within the form tag:

```
<form action="/edit">
</form>
```

Or, in your case, defining it in the html attribute section:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Comments", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-control", action = "/edit" })
```

If you do not define a particular action within the form tag, the form will assume you are just performing a post-back on the page itself.  You can also define the action on the button itself using:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10" formaction="/edit">Submit</button>
```

You can learn more about actions and formactions at w3Schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

Comment: he's not defining an action but he IS specifying two different controller functions to post to.  Shouldn't that be good enough?